# Работа с параллельным потоком

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

В программе класс SurfaceView выводит на экран игровую графику в параллельном потоке. В бесконечном цикле он перерисовывает графические объекты. В пользовательском потоке я обрабатываю нажатия на экран. При нажатии на кнопки НОВАЯ ИГРА программа инициализирует графические объекты (удаляет, обнуляет и т.д.) Класс SurfaceView перед тем как рисовать какой-то графический объект проверяет не равен ли он null? И всё работает нормально, но не всегда. Я предполагаю, что иногда удаление объекта при нажатии на кнопку НОВАЯ ИГРА попадает происходит именно между проверкой объекта на null и его рисованием. Т.е. SurfaceView проверяет объект на null(существует ли он), а пользовательский поток тут же удаляет этот объект. В следующий момент SurfaceView пытается вывести графический объект на экран и выдаёт ошибку, что объект не существует (=null). Я не уверен, что всё именно так происходит, но по другому объяснить редкие периодические ошибки не могу. Я поступил так: при нажатии НОВАЯ ИГРА я запрещаю SurfaceView выводить графические объекты на экран(устанавливаю boolean флаг = false), и только после того, как все объекты обновлены разрешаю обновление экрана (флаг = true). Подскажите, это правильный способ или эту задачу нужно решать по другому?

Comment: Приведите код, а так же ошибку из лога. Тогда сможем что-то подсказать

Comment: canvas.drawBitmap(gameField.getGameBalls()[x][y].getBitmap(), gameField.getGameBalls()[x][y].getRect(), dstRect, null); Эта строка иногда выдаёт ошибку, что gameField.getGameBalls()[x][y].getBitmap() равен null

Comment: Не вставляйте код в комментарий, все равно  него ничего не понять.

Comment: Решать такие вопросы без исходников вряд ли кто-то возьмётся, а так, могу посоветовать почитать про синхронизацию потоков

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов два.

1. делайте проверку на null (возьмите это за привычку)

   ```
    if (_temp != null) { код }
   ```
2. оберните на исключение

   ```
   try {
    код
   } catch (NullPointerException e) {
   }
   ```